# jQuery(document).ready() does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know why jQuery document ready might not fire on a website? I put exactly this script in footer and it simply doesn't fire (jQuery 1.8 is included in head section):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
     alert('test');
     jQuery("#slideshow iframe").each(function(){ 
          alert('test');
     });
});
</script>
```

There are no Javascript errors, console is empty and when I run this in Firebug's console it works:

```
jQuery("#slideshow iframe").each(function(){ 
     alert('test');
});
```

Comment: not even the first `alert('test');` fires ?

Comment: Yes, not even first... I have no explanation for this.

Comment: are you calling `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` somewhere else **before**?

Comment: It looks good based on what you describe, but it sounds like the script in the footer is never reached. Can you make a jsFiddle for us to try to reproduce it?

Comment: Yes, in many places, all are broken. This happens only on actual server and not on my localhost.

Comment: @GionaF, this would not explain the problem. You can register several `ready` handlers, and they will all be called in registration order.

Comment: @jimp It works on my localhost with the same exact files but not on actual server. jQuery is included. I can't reproduce in jsfiddle because there it will work :)

Comment: I added website address.

Comment: @Paul Your jquery link is broken, open  dev tool (F12) and look at network tab

Comment: @webdeveloper I see "status 200 OK" for jQuery. The path is correct.

Comment: @webdeveloper Actually now I see that Firebug doesn't show some errors but Chrome does... Thanks for suggestion. I think that now I see what is wrong.

Comment: @Paul Yes, your link works fine as I can see, but you have some problem with it `TypeError: $ is not a function`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: not necessarily true. If a handler throws an error, further handlers might not get called.

Comment: @Tgr, although it is not documented AFAICT, it is true in my tests that all subsequent handlers will fail to run, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently getting this error on your page

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

The cause of this error is inside your `flow.anything-slider-1.0.js` at line `11`.

The file is using `jQuery(document).ready()`, so `$` is not defined.

Changing line `11` from using `$` to `jQuery` works:

```
// doesn't work
$("#content").before("<div id=\"cycledump\"></div>");

// Does work
jQuery("#content").before("<div id=\"cycledump\"></div>");
```

The whole file uses jQuery instead of `$` so the file should probably stick with the one way of using jQuery instead of mixing it up.

**Edit**
I just double checked the [**.ready()**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) documentation and the following paragraph was interesting as it seems to relate to the issue:

> **Aliasing the jQuery Namespace**
>   When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call `$.noConflict()` to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is called, the `$` shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write `jQuery` each time we would normally write `$`.
>
> However, the handler passed to the `.ready()` method can take an argument, which is passed to the global jQuery object. This means we can rename the object within the context of our `.ready()` handler without affecting other code:
>
> ```
> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
>   // Code using $ as usual goes here.
> });
> ```

This would imply, that instead of fixing line `11` you could also change your fist line to `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`, passing the `$` as an argument. This might allow you then to use `$` throughout the file as well as jQuery.

Anyway, not sure passing `$` as an argument would work in your case, I just thought I mention it in case it does work.

Comment: Fixed :) Thanks! I didn't notice that because Firebug wasn't showing the error... Only Chrome Developer Tools showed it.

Comment: @Paul: That's what I was using and it helped in pin-pointing the problem alright.

Answer (score 5):

While that was not the case in this specific instance, one very annoying way in which this can happen is [jQuery bug 10251](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10251): an error in a `$(document).ready()` callback will prevent all callbacks registered after it from running. (In this case there will be a Javascript error, it might look completely unrelated, though.)

Answer (score 1):

It can be jQuery library path issue. Try loading it from [**jquery.com**](http://jquery.com) -

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
     alert('test');
});

</script>
```

Copy this code and paste in `head` section

Edit:

You are using `jQuery 1.4.2` and `1.8 jQuery UI`

Try moving the `script tag` in `head` section, it should work